# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with Audio Stream

Tags: java, android, streaming

I'm a total beginner with Android and Java. I've developed this simple app to stream audio, but it keeps crashing unexpectedly. Android Studio throws no errors, and I haven't been able to figure this out so far.

Here's my code:

> **`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jacob.wutk" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".radio" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

> **`activity_radio.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jacob.wutk.radio"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/play"
           android:layout_width="0.0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/play"
           android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
           android:layout_weight="1.0"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:onClick="playMusic"/>
       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/pause"
           android:layout_width="0.0dip"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:src="@drawable/pause"
           android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
           android:layout_weight="1.0"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:onClick="pauseMusic"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

> **`radio.java`**

```
public class radio extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Called when the user touches the button */
    public void playMusic(View view) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://streamer.cci.utk.edu:8000/wutk-vorbis"; // your URL here
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pauseMusic(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
    }
}
```

Crash Log.

```
--------- beginning of crash
07-13 09:34:35.175 2764-2764/com.example.jacob.wutk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.jacob.wutk, PID: 2764
                                                                      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 579537516 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 382MB until OOM
                                                                          at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                          at com.example.jacob.wutk.radio.onCreate(radio.java:30)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-13 09:34:42.066 2764-2764/com.example.jacob.wutk I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2764 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Show crash log and when it is crashing?

Comment: The app wouldn't just crash with no logcat output. Show what happens in logcat right at the crash.

Comment: Please post your crash log. If you are using Android studio and its not showing any crash log then try invalidate cache and restart and then post a crash log.

Comment: I guess it is crashing with `networkOnMainThreadException`. You should not call url in Main thread. Use a worker thread/AsyncTask which will download content concorrently.

Comment: post the "Android Monitor" Log.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, I only have a few hours of experience with this language and IDE.

Comment: How big is the image 'background' that you're setting on the imageView? Because you logcat say's you are running out of memory while decoding a bitmap.

Comment: 1.66 MB @WadeWilson

Comment: Try removing the line 'android:src="@drawable/background"' and rerunning the app. If it doesn't crash the problem is that the image you are  loading is too large in memory.

Comment: @WadeWilson that's it. Make it an answer and I'll mark it. Now to fix the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your OutOfMemoryError exception is because you are setting a large bitmap as the source for an ImageView inside of the xml layout 'activity_radio.xml'. When the layout is being inflated in your Activity/Fragment the ImageView is attempting to load the 'src' image in its full size in memory, which may not seem to large but the system may not have the proper memory to accommodate it.

What you want to do to fix this problem is to remove inside of your xml code, that sets the image and instead load the image on demand inside of your activity/fragment in a scaled down/up to properly fit your devices configuration.

Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to an article on the Android developers site that discusses properly loaded a scaled bitmap. Remember you want to handle loading and scaling the bitmap in a background thread to not block your UI thread otherwise you'll get another exception.